google colab :TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Code from Google Colab:
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import numpy as np

STOCK = pdr.get_data_tiingo('TSM', api_key='64dbe0a7e978cc2501fcc1e56aaf1935c63f78de')
STOCK = STOCK.reset_index(level=[0,1])
STOCK.index = STOCK['date']
STOCK_adj = STOCK.iloc[:, 7:12]
STOCK_adj.columns = ['Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume']
STOCK_adj

Traceback:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-ca49edb453ba> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 STOCK = pdr.get_data_tiingo('TSM', api_key='64dbe0a7e978cc2501fcc1e56aaf1935c63f78de')
      2 STOCK = STOCK.reset_index(level=[0,1])
      3 STOCK.index = STOCK['date']
      4 STOCK_adj = STOCK.iloc[:, 7:12]
      5 STOCK_adj.columns = ['Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume']

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in get_data_tiingo(*args, **kwargs)
    118 
    119 def get_data_tiingo(*args, **kwargs):
--> 120     return TiingoDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
    121 
    122 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/tiingo.py in read(self)
    232             finally:
    233                 self.close()
--> 234         return pd.concat(dfs, self._concat_axis)
    235 
    236 

TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

google colab return
TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I've searched for the whole night but still can't figure it out

The used version of pandas_datareader is outdated, it would need a pandas version before 1.5

@MichaelButscher is there an associated PR or issue you know of?

@jasonm One open issue from Jan 4, 2022 https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/922 and another from Jun 8, 2023 even with a fix https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/965
